# Why cannot I read a file line by line in a Perl script?

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script, which has to read a file line by line.

Line in the file:

```
0060|9592014|A001-9592014-0060|82769|NOVARTIS PHARMA SERVICES AG        BASEL|51671|NOVARTIS AG|A+|SWITZERLAND|Guarantees Issued|12/31/2016|12/31/2016|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|29014.0967835279993469339764885601502052|0||||0|1|550.3648|32541||.32|SUIG|OLEG|AAA||||||END|
```

I need to get only 32 fields, the first 32.

```
open (PRISM, "$infile") or die "Can't open $infile\n";
while (my $file_line = <PRISM>)
{
  last if ($file_line=~/^PRISMEXP/);
  next if ($file_line=~/^(\s)*$/);  # Skip blank lines
  print "LINE: $file_line\n";    # This line doesn't print anything
  my @field = (split /\|/, $file_line[0-32]);
  print "$field[0]\n";  #This line doesn't print anything
}
```

And as you can see, this part of code doesn't read the file and doesn't print anything. Why? Where is my mistake?

Comment: What's the content of `$infile`? If the first line begins with `PRISMEXP` you will never print anything.

Comment: If this is a proper csv file, you might be best off using `Text::CSV` to parse it.

Comment: If you had `use strict` turned on, you could never have made this mistake. The statement `$file_line[0-32]` is -- besides not being an array slice --  trying to take a value from the *array* `@file_line`, which does not exist. Which `strict` would have told you.

Answer (score 3):

Where you have `WHILE` you should have `while`.

Also, your blank line check should have `=~`, not `=`.

Your `split` uses `$file_line[0-32]` is the same thing as `$file_line[-32]`, which is the 32nd element from the end of `@file_line`, but you haven't set that array anywhere; I'm guessing that should be `substr($file_line,0,32)`. 
Or, if you only want the first 32 fields, it should be:

```
my @field;
@field[0..31] = split /\|/, $file_line;
```

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. It would have caught the last error, and likely the second error too.

Comment: I have while, I corrected it. reading is not working

Comment: I did it, still not working. Should I use $_ ?

Comment: @TLP: How is `0-32` interpreted as  `-2`?

Comment: @ikegami Yes, I ran some test code where I used `0 - 2`, after which I edited the comment, hence the mistake. I will delete my comment as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some notes on your program that should help you improve your success rate

- *Always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program, if you haven't done that already
- Use lexical file handles, like `my $prism_fh` instead of global bareword file handles like `PRISM`
- Don't put scalar variables inside double quotes. At best it will make no difference, and at worst you will get a completely different string
- *Always* put the `$!` variable in your `die` string when checking the status of `open` calls. It will tell you *why* the open failed. Also, perl will add the source file name and line number to the output of `die` *unless* you put a newline on the end of your string, so don't do that if you want to know where in your code the error occurred
- It is often better to use the default variable `$_` when reading from a file. Many operators use it as their default parameter, making for more concise and tidy code
- Don't forget `unless`. You can more cleanly check whether a line contains non-blanks by using `next unless $file_line =~ /\S/`
- If you don't `chomp` the input lines then there is no need to put a newline on the end when you print the output
- You need to `split` lines before you can select fields from the input `$file_line[0-32]` isn't valid Perl

Here's your Perl code refactored so that it prints the first 32 pipe-separated fields. I hope it is obvious that it needs a preamble that does `use strict` and `use warnings` and defines `$infile`.

```
open my $prism_fh, '<', $infile or die qq{Can't open "$infile": $!\n};

while (<$prism_fh>) {     
  next unless /\S/;
  last if /^PRISMEXP/;
  chomp;
  my @fields = (split /\|/);
  print join('|', @fields[0 .. 31]), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
0060|9592014|A001-9592014-0060|82769|NOVARTIS PHARMA SERVICES AG        BASEL|51671|NOVARTIS AG|A+|SWITZERLAND|Guarantees Issued|12/31/2016|12/31/2016|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|29014.0967835279993469339764885601502052|0||||0|1|550.3648|32541||.32
```

---

**Update**

Instead of splitting and recombining, you could use a regular expression to grab the first 32 pipe-separated fields, like this

```
while (<$prism_fh) {     
  next unless /\S/;
  last if /^PRISMEXP/;
  chomp;
  print $1, "\n" if /^((?:[^|]*\|){31}[^|]*)/;
}
```

The output is identical to that of the program above.

Comment: Another excellent response thanks for your contributions!  I'm assuming the regexp version here is faster because it avoids two function calls (`split` and `join`) which are higher overhead for the compiler compared to the super optimized regex engine.

Comment: @G.Cito: It shouldn't matter which is faster unless one of them is too slow for your needs. You should choose the solution that is most clear to you.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the line:

```
last if ($file_line=~/^PRISMEXP/);
```

If the first line of `$infile` begins with PRISMEXP you will never print anything.

You have also to change the line:

```
my @field = (split /\|/, $file_line[0-32]);
```

to:

```
my @field = (split /\|/, $file_line)[0..32];
```

Comment: when I print $_, it works. Now I have to cut only 32 fields.How can I do it?

Comment: @user2843135: Edit your question and add an extract of your input file.

Comment: I have 100 lines pipe delimeter in the file, which I open and try to read from the file line by line using only 32 fields (32|333|ee and so on. All amount of fields are 44. I need only first 32.

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you. I will use it. The only problem is that I only change the existing program, made 15 years ago, and the boss doesn't want to change what is working  very long time. But thank you anyway. Everything was very helpfull.